# Need help with understanding IP blocks

Tags: joomla, ip-address, cloudflare

I'm trying to troubleshoot some problems with users being blocked from our website by CloudFlare. We run a Joomla 2.5 installation with RSFirewall. I have the list of IP blocks that CloudFlare uses, but I'm not versed enough with IP block math to figure out whether several of the addresses that are currently showing in the blacklist are actually CF servers. For example, the following IP is in our blacklist:

103.22.201.147

And CloudFlare uses the following block:

103.22.200.0/22

Based on what I read [here](http://gr8idea.info/os/tutorials/security/iptables7.html) it looks like that address is indeed a CloudFlare address and I need to remove it from the blacklist. Can anybody confirm whether I'm understanding it correctly or not? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do not get to say this enough- but Welcome to the Webmasters StackExchange! The people here are excellent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The IP address 103.22.201.147 is CloudFlare within the IP address range of 103.22.200.0 - 103.22.201.255.

Answer (score 3):

If it helps at all the CIDR range converts to:

103.22.200.0-103.22.203.255

Comment: One up-vote! You were fast and precise. I just happen to have local CGI(s) that I use for my research that allows me to figure these things out quickly. Otherwise, you would have gotten the full nod. Thanks for answering!

Comment: I'll upvote that as well once I have enough reputation. Thank you for confirming his answer and clarifying IP blocks for me!